# How do I remove a subdomain that I created on meteor.com

Tags: meteor

I created a subdomain on [meteor.com](http://meteor.com) to try it out, but now I'm moving on to a new domain so want to remove the existing subdomain on Meteor. I didn't set any password to the subdomain. I'm really confused on how to remove it from [meteor.com](http://meteor.com).  I also deleted the local repository that I had from my machine. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it through the command line like you did to deploy on meteor.com.

To delete a meteor.com deployment, just run the same command with the `--delete` flag:

```
# navigate to your Meteor project 
cd /...
meteor deploy --delete
```

According to the command documentation:

> The --delete flag permanently removes a deployed application, including
>   all of its stored data.

You can always get more information about a command by running `meteor help` followed by the command name:

```
meteor help deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just wanted to make an addition to it for those following this thread.**

```
meteor deploy <example.meteor.com> --delete (This is the proper command. Replace example with your subdomain)
```

You might want to login to your local repo before initialising the `--delete` command

```
meteor login --email 'email-id-used-to-login-at-meteor.com' 

You'll be prompted to input email-id and password. Then you're logged in!
```

*Hope this helps.*